# PhoneGap + Android + AdMob = Network is Unavailable?

Tags: android, cordova, admob

Been after this issue for 3 weeks now. It started happening after removing two third party plugins and I think somehow was helping admob work, whether due to code delay or something else. Last week, I rebuilt the entire project from scratch and got it to work fairly well but it has started again. I've also changed development OS from Ubuntu to Win8 just in case and that didn't solve it either.

My feeling is that the admob sdk is losing the ability to query the network. The app itself works and requires the ability to use internet. So, the app itself has internet permissions. If I were to restart the app, sometimes it will work, some times it won't. If I put it in test mode, it should always work, but I still get the following error (and on subsequent refreshes during this session):

```
07-14 12:21:12.600: I/Ads(13271): Request scenario: Offline with no buffered ads.
07-14 12:21:12.600: I/Ads(13271): Network is unavailable.  Aborting ad request.
07-14 12:21:12.610: I/Ads(13271): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
```

I've noticed that the url is being modified in the google SDK. I clipped some of the results for reasons since it contains info I'd rather not share.

```
07-14 12:21:12.175: I/Ads(13271): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script>
07-14 12:21:12.585: I/Ads(13271): Received ad url: <url: "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=0&session_id=17668451291953494526
07-14 12:21:12.600: I/Ads(13271): Ad url modified to http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=0&session_id=17668451291953494526&seq_num=1&u_w=360
```

I am using Admob 6.4.1 but I upgraded to 6.4.1 because I was getting the same thing with 6.3.1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
package="com.atomicent.blazereader"
android:versionCode="27"
android:versionName="1.14" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
     >

    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.atomicent.blazereader.BlazeReader"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Activity java file:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.init();
    super.appView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000); 
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    super.appView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
    {

        @Suppress
        public void RateApp()
        {
            LoadPage(getString(R.string.blazeReaderLink));
            return;
        }

        @Suppress
        public void writeLog(String tag, String textBlock)
        {
            Log.i(tag, textBlock);
            return;
        }

        @Suppress
        public void setPageUrl(String url)
        {
            pageUrl = url;
            return;
        }

        @Suppress
        public void refreshPage(String url)
        {
            mGaTracker.sendView(url);
            GAServiceManager.getInstance().dispatch();
            return;
        }

        @Suppress
        public void SendException(String exception) 
        {
            mGaTracker.sendException(exception, false);
            GAServiceManager.getInstance().dispatch();
            return;
        }

        @Suppress
        public void OpenInBrowser()
        {
            OpenBrowserAction();
            return;
        }

        @Suppress
        public void EmailFeedback()
        {
            SendFeedbackAction();
            return;
        }

        @Suppress
        public void RefreshApp()
        {
            RefreshAction();
            return;
        }

        @Suppress
        public void BlazeReaderPro()
        {
            LoadPage(getString(R.string.blazeReaderProLink));
            return;
        }

        @Suppress
        public void OtherAppsLink()
        {
            LoadPage(getString(R.string.otherAtomicAppsLink));
            return;
        }

        @Suppress
        public void BlazeFacebook()
        {
            BlazeReaderFacebookAction();
            return;
        }

        @Suppress
        public void LoadCompleted()
        {
            //doAdMob();
            return;
        }

        @Suppress
        public void shareInterface(String subject, String title, String textBlock)
        {
            mGaTracker.sendEvent("ui_action", "share", pageUrl, null);
            GAServiceManager.getInstance().dispatch();

            ShareIntent(getActivity(), subject, title, textBlock, "text/plain");

            return;
        }
    },"MyAndroid");

    mGaInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    mGaTracker = mGaInstance.getTracker(getString(R.string.ga_trackingId));

    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            doAdMob();
        }
    }, 5000); 
}

  protected void doAdMob()
  {
      // Create the adView
        AdSize adSize;

        String screenType = getString(R.string.screen_type); 

        if(screenType.equals("1"))
        {
            adSize = AdSize.BANNER;
        }
        else if(screenType.equals("2"))
        {
            adSize = AdSize.IAB_BANNER;
        }
        else if(screenType.equals("3"))
        {
            adSize = AdSize.IAB_LEADERBOARD;
        }
        else
        {
            adSize = AdSize.BANNER;
        }


        AdView adView = new AdView(this, adSize, "pubID");      
        LinearLayout layout = super.root;
        layout.addView(adView);

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        request.addTestDevice("B00EF0D66CFCBE408653D4FFE7DF8C2A");
        request.addTestDevice("9B556DEC8E1B587D9DE1910F4D8ECFDC");
        adView.loadAd(request);
        adView.setAdListener(this);
  }
```

In the code AdView, I removed my pubID for the purpose of publishing it here. Some help is greatly needed. What's going on? Anyone had this issue? I've read every post about this in stackoverflow and other places, but none have anything that works. I've also cleaned the project a few times as well. Is there some setting that might prevent admob from being able to query the network?

Comment: I want to add that previous to this week I was using Cordova 2.5. I am using Cordova 2.9 this week but that has not resolved it. I am also using Google Admob 6.4.1 but was also using 6.3.1 prior to this week. The target SDK is 4.2.2 (17).

Comment: I rebuilt the project from a different app that works 100% with admob and after setting it back up, I have learned that the issue seems to be the ad being modified (see log entry: Ad url modified to...). The new project doesn't do that.   Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that the issue was due to an incorrect config.xml file. For whatever reason, it stopped being compatible with the project that I had. The project that I used as a basis for admob working 100%, did not have a config.xml file and thus didn't have any conflict (at least from the admob point of view).

After 15 retests and 0 failures, I believe this was the correct fix. The config.xml file should read something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.origin.packagename"
    versionCode="27" 
    version   = "1.14">

<!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

<name>App Name</name>

<description>
    An example for phonegap build docs. 
</description>

<author href="http://www.url.com" email="email.com">
    Author Name
</author>

<preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.9.0" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>

<!-- to enable individual permissions use the following examples -->
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>

<access origin="*" />
</widget>
```